# how to pass arguments to Mutation in VelocityX flutter

Tags: flutter

I have simple store

```
class MyStore extends VxStore {
  Object user = {};
}
```

and trying to pass arguments to mutation class

```
SaveUser(userData);
```

but I unable to receive arguments show error undefined name

```
class SaveUser extends VxMutation<MyStore> {
  SaveUser(userData);

  perform() => {print(userData)};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see a fellow Vx user suffering for an answer. I feel you brother.

Pass arguments Same as regular class constructor.

```
class SaveUser extends VxMutation<MyStore> {
  SaveUser(this.userData);
Object? userData;
@override
  void perform() {
print(userData?);
};
}
```

Use it like this:

```
onTap: () => SaveUser(userData)
```